# How is additive error handled in this simple algorithm? 'Product of all elements'

Tags: ds.algorithms, approximation-algorithms, upper-bounds, analysis-of-algorithms

Say we have two unit vectors $\hat{u}, \hat{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\hat{u} = (u_1,...,u_n)$ and $\hat{v}$ approximates  $\hat{u}$. $~\hat{v} = (u_1+\epsilon, ...,u_n+\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon = \frac{1}{poly(n)}$.

We have an algorithm which takes the product of all elements and outputs the product. For the exact case (with $\hat{u}$), $x = \prod_i^nu_i$. For the approximate case (with $\hat{v}$), 
$x^* = \prod_i^n(u_i + \epsilon)$.

What is the error of $x^*$ with respect to $x$? How do we bound the error of $x^*$ in terms of epsilon? How is the error analysis typically handled in this situation?

Comment: Do you really mean it is the same $\epsilon$ in each coordinate, or do you perhaps mean $(u_1+\epsilon_1,\dots,u_n+\epsilon_n)$?  Do you care about relative error or absolute error?

Comment: 1) this is neither computer science, nor research level. 2) your notation needs to be fixed the way @DW suggested. 3) already for $n=2$ you can see that $|x^* - x|$ can be as large as $\epsilon(u_1+u_2) + \epsilon^2$ and will not be a function of only $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Use Taylor series expansion for the function $\prod_{i=1}^{n} (u_i + y)$ around $y=0$ to obtain the error as $\epsilon (\prod_{j=1}^{n} u_j) \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_i^{-1} + O(\epsilon^2)$. Note that Taylor series works for $\epsilon = O(1/poly(n))$, because $\mathbf{u}$ is a unit normed vector and the product $\prod_{j=1}^{n} u_j < 1$.

Comment: I'm having some slight difficulty parsing this. Should it be "obtain the error as $\epsilon = ...$? Also, can we make a statement about how wrong our algorithm can be just in terms of $\epsilon$? Thanks! Still trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: $n\epsilon+ O(\epsilon^2)$ should work